# Importing Data Dictionary (DDF) into QGIS (Fields)

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

Are there any tips/tricks on getting all the Attributes from a data dictionary for a GPS unit to sync with the Fields in a QGIS style?

Right now, in order to update the drop-down options in QGIS, I have had to semi-manually enter and update the Fields and Values when any of the data dictionary items change (Trimble). The default "Widget" type for imported shapefiles in QGIS is "Text Edit," I have to change that to "Value Map" or other widget type and import the fields/values via csv for each field. Any way to automate that process by importing a DDF or other method?  I have ~100 Attributes/Field types.